# WooCommerce hook that returns products delete from cart

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook

Hy guys.
I have three product in my cart. Let's try to imagine that the image is the cart and i have modify the quantity of product and then press update cart.

[image]

When i press update cart, my function runs, than prints all my item after modify, into ITEMS.json. There are all my items and with the quantity modify of the Shoes, but into my file there is also Hoodie with quantity = 3. How is it possible that i delete it? it and i print items after update cart.

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_cart_item_quantity_update','my_function');

function my_function()
{

    global $woocommerce;    
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
    file_put_contents('ITEMS.json', print_r($items, true));
}
```

Is there something to distinguish the products delete from product modify?

Is there a hook which returns the list of products deleted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, you can retrieve all needed information from the parameters of the hooked function:

```
function my_function( $cart_item_key, $quantity, $old_quantity ) {
    global $woocommerce;  
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

    // Check that quantity is not equal to 0 and that the item exists in the cart
    if($quantity && isset($items[$cart_item_key])) {
        $content = '';
        // TODO: Here you must fill $content with needed information from $items[$cart_item_key]
        // Below, I add the new quatity to the $content string.
        $content .= $quantity;
        // Write in JSON file
        file_put_contents('ITEMS.json', $content);
    }
};

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_item_quantity_update', 'my_function', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: global $woocommerce; 
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
file_put_contents('ITEMS.json', print_r($items, true));

foreach($items as $item => $values) 
{ 
 $_product =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id()); 
 
 $quantity_modify=$values['quantity'];
} I have this code, i insert your if into for?

Comment: where are they  passed quantity and old_quantity ?

Comment: $quantity is the new quantity of the product, and $old_quantity are the former one.

Comment: Your code can't run because as i said before, when i remove one product and i press update cart, the hook called, but doesen't distinguish, the products remove with product modify; therefore the product removed(T-Shirt) will have quantity equal to that inserted.